# Struggling to decode a JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this json I get from an API:

```
{
    "product_id": "id",
    "name": "name",
    "manufacturer": "manufacturer",
    "image_url": "url",
    "additional_info": "",
    "store_id": "id",
    "store_name": "name",
    "owner_id": "id",
    "quantities": [
        {
            "ml": 1,
            "price": 2
        },
        {
            "ml": 1,
            "price": 2
        },
        {
            "ml": 1,
            "price": 2
        },
        {
            "ml": 1,
            "price": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the model I have:

```
struct Quantity: Codable {
    var ml: Int
    var price: Float

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case ml = "ml"
        case price = "price"
    }
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let uuid: String
    let productName: String
    let productManufacturer: String
    let productImage: String
    let quantities: [Quantity]
    let additionalInfo: String?
    let storeID: String
    let storeName: String
    let ownerID: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case uuid = "product_id"
        case productName = "name"
        case productManufacturer = "manufacturer"
        case productImage = "image_url"
        case quantities = "quantities"
        case additionalInfo = "additional_info"
        case storeID = "store_id"
        case storeName = "store_name"
        case ownerID = "owner_id"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to decode this, but I get this error:

```
Failed to decode json:  typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

This is how I decode the JSON:

```
func fetchGenericData<T: Decodable>(request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping(T) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            //TODO: Handle error.
            print(error)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let object = try self.decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(object)
        }catch let jsonError{
            print("Failed to decode json: ", jsonError)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I understand the error, but I don't know how to fix it.

I don't know what is wrong here, I thought maybe the `Quantity`, but, to me, it looks like it should decode it just fine, just as "product_id" has value, so each quantity object has it's key and it's value, that doesn't look like a dictionary to me.
Is the problem even in the Quantity object?

Comment: It's not about your question, but you don't need to define you coding keys if it's match with the key name. `case ml, price` enough

Comment: How do you call fetchGenericData in this case?

Comment: If I take your code and decode it directly in my playground without using the function everything works fine so it is definitely your call to the function that is wrong.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you. I just looked too, and there was a simple error on the server side code, which I didn't notice.

Comment: Server side code? You mean the json was incorrect?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It didn't return, I had a piece of outdated code, that I forgot I fixed, so It returned an error. I didn't saw it until I sent a request in Postman.

Comment: @Dris Thank you, it's just a habit, because Product has coding keys, I had to write coding keys for Quantity as well so it will be kinda symmetric(?) I guess xD.

Comment: So the answer you accepted has nothing to do with your solution to the problem?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Actually, it kinda does, because it reminded me to check the server side code, but I guess you are, maybe it's against SO rules, so I will remove the accepted.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is You seem to be trying to decode an array of products but actually it only returning a dictionary that contains only one product. Try this code which tries to decode your `JSON` into a single product and it should fix the issue:

```
fetchGenericData(request: request) { (product: Product) in
    print(product)
}
```

Instead of what you might be doing right now which could look like this:

```
fetchGenericData(request: request) { (products: [Product]) in
    print(product)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about the server side code xP there was a simple problem there.

Comment: Oh, you mean there was some code wrapping the product dictionary?

Comment: Actually, I wrapped something in an array, which caused an error because of a change I did, I totally forgot about it, and it returned error. I only remembered to check in Postman after reading your guys comments (also the comments to my question), and I saw I get an error instead of the JSON I want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `try JSONDecoder().decode(Product.self, from: data)`

I think you pass [Product].self